# Extracting a variable name from a String in Java

Tags: java, android

So I'm writing a rather crude RPG game for android right. It's more of a testing my skills than anything else.  I"m working on the player class and I have stats like so:

```
int health = 3;
int strength = 3;
int knowledge = 3;
int resolve = 3;
int empathy = 3;
int xp = 0;
int statpoints = 0;
int level = 1;
int cap = 2 * level;
int capCounter = 0;
int TotalHealth = 2 * health + level;
```

Later in the code I have a method is meant to take in the name of the stat and attempt to increase it if it can

```
   private void updateStat(String stat) {
    if (capCounter < cap) {
        if (statpoints >= 2 * cap * level) {



            capCounter++;

            if (capCounter <= cap) {
                statpoints = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("You don't have enough points");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("Yout must level up first");
    }

}
```

That big blank space represents an area of code where I want to parse the String "stat" and extract from it the name of the stat that I'm trying to update, then update that stat by 1. Is there a way to do this?

oh and the System.out.print calls are currently for testing purposes. They'll be replaced with Toasts as soon as I can figure out how to work with Toasts in the updates version of Android Studio. I've been getting errors with the way I used to call makeText.

Comment: Are you planning on using "stat" to hold whatever status you are sending to the function?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. It is called [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). Whether you want to go down this road is another topic.

Comment: i wonder if your problem was solved, if yes could you please turn your question as resolved by choosing correct answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the apache [BeanUtils library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/), and the  [PropertyUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#standard.basic) class.

The code you need is

`PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(yourPlayer, "yourField", "yourValue");`

The longuest answer is to use de reflec API, which allow you to manipulate object, like read/write attributes, annotation and many more : Javadoc Here[enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html)

A another information, you make and android application, the use of the reflect api is discouraged for performance reason. Maybe the best solution for you is to have a Map containing all differents stats

```
Map<String, Integer> statsValue = new HashMap<>();
statsValue.put("health", 3);
statsValue.get("health");
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have a lot of stats, and that you want to access them by the name of the stat, rather than an index number, you should be using a defined data structure, rather than dozens of variables.

Many solutions have been recommended, but one of the fastest, and great to learn solutions is a **HashMap**. It allows you to search for the data by key (i.e. 'health');

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hashMap.put("health", 1);
hashMap.put("strenght", 1);
.
.
.
```

and then to you can get values by string stat like this

```
hashMap.get(StatString)
```

Good luck !

Comment: So am I basically creating a hash table with each value and then retrieving them in the method call based on the string I pass into the updatestat method?

Comment: yes you can manipulate the values inside the hashmap using a string key

Comment: I'm running into an error when I try to use the HashMap. I've imported 

import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.HashMap

But it still can't resolve the .put method.

Comment: you only have to import java.util.HashMap and make sure that the parameter of put are (a string , an Integer) like defined in the instanciation, if you still have trouble , please put your code